# Cloning a Morea Framework Site

Tags: morea-framework

Is there a workflow (or a best practice) for setting up a new course based on an exiting one? Seems to be missing from the [documentation](http://morea-framework.github.io/quickstart.html).

Ideally I would just fork the course at github.com and then clone it, but this does not set-up the directory structure (is it enough to just clone the master and gh-pages branches + scripts?).

I believe I would also like to [merge-upstream](http://morea-framework.github.io/userguide.html#morea-merge-upstream) updates from the core framework before further developing the new course.  Or maybe better to just start a new one from scratch and then copy the actual content?

Any other recommended steps? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different approaches that people use:

- One professor just keeps a single repo and "refreshes" the course (changing the dates, etc.) from semester to semester.
- Another approach is to create a fresh repo, set the old course as the upstream master, and then merge.  That keeps your old course published and initializes the new one with the contents of the old one. (This is a good approach if you have made extensive customizations to the framework for your course).
- A third approach is to create a new repo, follow the Quickstart instructions to initialize it to an empty Morea site, then simply copy the morea/ folder from your old site to your new site.  That's a nice approach if you don't make customizations, since your new repo history doesn't include all the stuff from the prior semester.

Regardless of how you do it, one common problem is updating all of the date fields from one semester to another.  One of the intrepid Morea hackers here at the University of Hawaii has developed a script to automate Morea date updating. He should be releasing his script for public consumption within a few weeks; we will update the [Morea News Page](http://morea-framework.github.io/news.html) when it's out.

Comment: Thanks, in case of a new repo - do I need to change the Google Analytics ID? (If possible, I prefer reusing it since most traffic will go to the new one anyhow)

Comment: I think you can use the same ID.